# Is this possible we can generate Pentaho report without using Pentaho User Console

Tags: pentaho, ofbiz

I have just use OFBiz to generate report but I want to see my reports in Pentaho. For that I have to open Pentaho page. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

you can generate pentaho reports without pentaho platform at all. Pentaho reporting engine is completely separate project, and you can embedd it where ever you want to embed it.

See examples how to programmatically generate report here: 
https://github.com/tmorgner/pentaho-reporting-oem-sdk

or other guide here:
https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/tree/master/engine/sdk/resources/documentation